# Nodemon: Ignore a single file in a monitored folder

Tags: nodemon

I have this `./src` folder which I like to monitor with `nodemon`

```
$> nodemon -e ts -w './src/**/*.ts' --exec ....
```

Now I would like to ignore a single file inside `./src`. Whatever I try, I cannot ignore any file inside `./src` :(

```
$> DEBUG=nodemon:watch nodemon -e ts -i './src/gen.ts' -w './src/**/*.ts' --exec ....
```

Is something like this possible?